# SQL - Incremental Case Statement - Cohort Analysis

Tags: sql, case, amazon-redshift

My main goal is to get a quick idea for the average revenue for users during a 30,90,180, 180+ day period.
I have an email, the date they joined a certain group, and a revenue date

```
create temporary table cohorts (
  email varchar(64)
, start_date timestamp
, purchase_date timestamp
, amount decimal(10,2)
)
;

insert into cohorts 
values 
  ('johnsmith@domain.com', '2020-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-01-01 12:00:00', '200.00')
, ('happyday@domain.com', '2020-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-02-28 00:00:00','100.00')
, ('happyday@domain.com', '2020-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-01-28 00:00:00','100.00')
, ('susieq@domain.com', '2020-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-05-01 00:00:00', '50.00')
, ('janedoe@domain.com', '2020-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-03-30 00:00:00', '75.00')
, ('janedoe@domain.com', '2020-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-07-30 00:00:00', '75.00')
;
```

If I wanted to see the average revenue for users during a certain time period I'd write something like:

```
select 
case 
    when datediff(day,start_date, purchase_date) < 30 then 'Within 30' 
    when datediff(day,start_date, purchase_date) < 90 then 'Within 90' 
    when datediff(day,start_date, purchase_date) < 180 then 'Within 180' 
    else 'Older than 180' 
end as cohort_flag 
, count(distinct email) num_of_emails 
, sum(amount) summed_amt 
, sum(amount)/count(distinct email) as avg_value 
from cohorts
group by 1 

  cohort_flag  num_of_emails  summed_amt  avg_value
     Within 30            2       300.0      150.0
     Within 90            2       175.0       87.5
    Within 180            1        50.0       50.0
Older than 180            1        75.0       75.0
```

However, since a case statement resolves to the first true clause, it doesn't include revenue from earlier "cohorts". My desired result would be below, where users in earlier cohorts are part of others:

```
  cohort_flag  num_of_emails  summed_amt  avg_value
     Within 30            2       300.0      150.0
     Within 90            3       475.0      158.33
    Within 180            4       525.0      131.25
Older than 180            4       600.0      150.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the same row of the table for more than 1 groups, so you need a query like this:

```
select 30 days_dif, 'Within 30' cohort_flag union all
select 90, 'Within 90' union all
select 180, 'Within 180' union all
select 2147483647, 'Older than 180'
```

(I hope the syntax is supported by Redshift)
which defines the groups and then `LEFT` join it to the table:

```
select t.cohort_flag, 
       count(distinct c.email) num_of_emails,
       coalesce(sum(c.amount), 0) summed_amt, 
       coalesce(sum(c.amount), 0) / nullif(count(distinct c.email), 0) as avg_value 
from (
  select 30 days_dif, 'Within 30' cohort_flag union all
  select 90, 'Within 90' union all
  select 180, 'Within 180' union all
  select 2147483647, 'Older than 180'
) t left join cohorts c
on datediff(day, c.start_date, c.purchase_date) < t.days_dif
group by t.days_dif, t.cohort_flag
order by t.days_dif
```

Comment: joining on `datediff(day, c.start_date, c.purchase_date) < t.days_dif` was brilliant.